# Headphones not working after update Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones

I have tried all the forum threads here concerning this problem, none of the provided solutions worked (some even made the problem worse). I have an Asus x551m Laptop with SonicMaster audio. Ubuntu 14.04 worked fine with both the Headphones and internal speaker. After updating to 14.04.1, my headphone jack stopped working but the internal speaker is working fine.

Comment: Are the headphones working on another device? Want to rule out the hardware. Does the headphones work if you run Ubuntu of a live-USB?

Comment: @Alvar The headphones work on all my other computers, and on the same computer running Windows 8.1. It seems that Ubuntu 14.04.1 is the only thing the headphone jack won't work with.

Comment: Have you tried newer/older versions of the kernel? Since that's where most of the drivers are located..

Comment: As I said in my post, the headphone jack worked perfectly on 14.04, but after updating to 14.04.1 it stopped working.

Comment: As I said in my comment, have you tried an older **kernel**. Because this sounds like a bug. Since it worked before. If it's a bug then report it so that it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to have fixed itself, an update that came out last week made my headphones work again.

Comment: Please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 22):

I spent a *long* time working with the same problem, based on lots of forum threads,  and nothing helped. Then I tried this:

```
$ alsactl restore
```

That did it :)

Comment: this work for me!

Comment: Great, that helped me after messing with Audacity and audio inputs, which ended up in extreme feedback that I thought completely damaged my hardware. I was having constant white noise from the headphone mic, and it would not detect headphones. `alsactl restore` fixed it all. Thanks!

Comment: I had hunted around all over the place for an answer, too! You fixed it in 2 seconds! LEGEND!

Answer (score 9):

I got it fixed by doing following:

1. open terminal and run `alsamixer`
2. when you plugin your headphones, this should be the configuration:

   ```
   master - 00,  64(need not be 64, can be any other value)
   headphones - 00, 100
   speakers MM, 0
   ```

In my case, headphones was showing `MM` instead of `00`. It can be changed by moving to headphones and pressing <kbd>m</kbd>.

Comment: This did it for me as well, with a SoundBlaster Recon3Di.

Comment: Worked in thinkpad t460 too, ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

I found this tip for Ubuntu 13.10 and it worked for me after I upgraded to 14.04.1, maybe it works for you as well? :)

"Probably, your Headphone Jack Sense is turned off..

Try this:

Open Terminal.
Type in alsamixer.
Locate and navigate to "Headphone".
Press m.
This should turn on your Headphone Jack Sense."