# Headphones not working after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, headphones

I'm a Ubuntu-newbie (1 month) and unable to understand why my headphones worked yesterday before bedtime - and now suddenly are not working after installing new update this morning.

Also I am too new and unexperienced to formulate the question correctly I'm sure :-)

Please help!

Comment: Is the headphone working fine on other devices and is the mentioned answer didn't work ?

Comment: My headphones are working on all other devices, yes.

Comment: do a `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` and restart and let us know if it helps. And please paste the __update commands you used__

Answer (score -1):

I am also a newbie to Ubuntu installed it just last week on my PC :) This helped me and I hope this helps you too ;)

Here is a [snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWyj0.png) of what my Unity GUI tells me about the Sound settings.

1. Go to the sound Settings -> Press the super key / winkey (Ex-Windows user) and type sound.
2. On the Output tab select the Headphones that is connected to the system.
3. Un-mute and change the output volume value.

I use VLC player so I changed some settings over there and made it stick into the changelog.

1. Open VLC Player
2. Select Tools | Preferences from the menu.
3. Open the Audio Tab and select All option at the bottom.This should result in a screen 'Advanced Preferences'.
4. Change the Audio -> Output module to ALSA audio output.
5. [Save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC5MI.png) the setting - using the Save Button in the lower left of the Screen.
6. Close the VLC Player (the setting will be applied the next time you open VLC)
7. Open VLC Player and select Tools | Preferences | Audio | Output modules | ALSA
8. If the USB Headphones you use are not in the list, then select the Refresh button.
9. Select the USB Headphones you use from the list, then select the Save button.

I did tinker around with a few other commands that I found here ([link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working), [link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518851/headphones-not-working-after-update-ubuntu-14-04-1), [link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545915/ubuntu-14-04-headphones-not-working))

Truth be told I am a newbie to this place and this is my first answer. I hope I helped at least a bit ＿φ(°-°=)

Comment: Thx for your reply. But I've decided Linux is not for me.

Comment: Well thats just sad, you should try it for some more time keep fighting :) Or something like that? No? Well it depends on what you need though ... I hope you find enough inner peace to get back to Ubuntu ;) @PeterMayRosenkilde

Comment: please specify what needs to be changed to help get the sound back and a good direction to where changes will be made is also good.

Comment: I am sorry for being a little air headed. But this is a hardware related question. For my PC I have headphones (JBL), a built in speaker(Antec ONE) and an external sound system (ALTEC). I don't exactly remember what my initial configurations were, I know this is one Noob Mistake. But there is a link to a snap of what my Headphones config is, and since I am not reputed enough to insert a pic I am really at a loss to put it into words here. But I hope you can comment on the edit that I made @George

Comment: Just go through your information and post the steps the OP should follow to resolve it and then add those links for reference. That would help your answer a lot.